# How to save something in Mongo in UUID type by Go?

Tags: mongodb, go

By MongoDB console I can add document:

```
{
        "_id": ObjectID(),
        "name": "John",
        "sign": UUID("32e79135-76c4-4682-80b2-8c813be9b792")
}
```

And next I can read it:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('64d4ce25ac7c4327e76a53e3'),
    name: "John",
    sign: UUID("32e7913576c4468280b28c813be9b792")
}
```

I can do:
 `db.getCollection('people').find({"sign": UUID("32e79135-76c4-4682-80b2-8c813be9b792")})`

And I can find the people.

But when I try it in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string    `bson:"name"`
    Sign uuid.UUID `bson:"sign"`
}

func main() {
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(context.Background())

    db := client.Database("mydatabase")
    collection := db.Collection("people")

    signUUID := uuid.New()

    person := Person{
        Name: "John",
        Sign: signUUID,
    }

    _, err = collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), person)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Document inserted successfully")
}
```

Then in Mongo I have:

`{ _id: ObjectId('64d4cf0a308251580cffee4e'), name: 'John', sign: BinData(0, 'wqaX6oYLT1eurEEhIciK9Q==') }`

I would like to have a "sign" field of type UUID and be able to easily search by it in Mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `github.com/google/uuid` does not implement the [bson.ValueMarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.12.1/bson#ValueMarshaler) interface to marshal itself into a mongodb UUID, that's why it does not work.

We can register our own codec to encode it to or decode it from mongodb UUID. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsonrw"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string    `bson:"name"`
    Sign uuid.UUID `bson:"sign"`
}

func main() {
    tUUID := reflect.TypeOf(uuid.Nil)
    bson.DefaultRegistry.RegisterTypeEncoder(tUUID, bsoncodec.ValueEncoderFunc(func(ec bsoncodec.EncodeContext, vw bsonrw.ValueWriter, val reflect.Value) error {
        // borrowed from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/89c7e1d1d9a2954472fe852baf27ecca9dbf9bbf/bson/bsoncodec/default_value_encoders.go#L684-L691
        if !val.IsValid() || val.Type() != tUUID {
            return bsoncodec.ValueEncoderError{Name: "UUIDEncodeValue", Types: []reflect.Type{tUUID}, Received: val}
        }
        uuid := val.Interface().(uuid.UUID)

        return vw.WriteBinaryWithSubtype(uuid[:], bson.TypeBinaryUUID)
    }))
    bson.DefaultRegistry.RegisterTypeDecoder(tUUID, bsoncodec.ValueDecoderFunc(func(dc bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
        // borrowed from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/89c7e1d1d9a2954472fe852baf27ecca9dbf9bbf/bson/bsoncodec/default_value_decoders.go#L694-L706
        if !val.CanSet() || val.Type() != tUUID {
            return bsoncodec.ValueDecoderError{Name: "UUIDDecodeValue", Types: []reflect.Type{tUUID}, Received: val}
        }

        var data []byte
        var subtype byte
        var err error
        switch vrType := vr.Type(); vrType {
        case bson.TypeBinary:
            data, subtype, err = vr.ReadBinary()
        case bson.TypeNull:
            err = vr.ReadNull()
        case bson.TypeUndefined:
            err = vr.ReadUndefined()
        default:
            err = fmt.Errorf("cannot decode %v into a Binary", vrType)
        }

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if subtype != bson.TypeBinaryUUID {
            return fmt.Errorf("cannot decode subtype %v into a UUID", subtype)
        }

        val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(uuid.UUID(data)))
        return nil
    }))

    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(context.Background())

    db := client.Database("mydatabase")
    collection := db.Collection("people")

    signUUID := uuid.New()

    person := Person{
        Name: "John",
        Sign: signUUID,
    }

    if _, err = collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), person); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var p Person

    if err := collection.FindOne(context.Background(),
        bson.M{"sign": signUUID},
    ).Decode(&p); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%+v\n", p)
}
```

See the discussion here: [Add support for mongodb UUID type](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-830?jql=project%20%3D%20GODRIVER%20AND%20text%20%7E%20uuid).

For the sake of completeness, below shows the approach that implements the `bson.ValueMarshaler` and `bson.ValueUnmarshaler` interfaces:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsontype"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx/bsoncore"
)

type myUUID struct {
    uuid.UUID
}

var (
    _ bson.ValueMarshaler   = (*myUUID)(nil)
    _ bson.ValueUnmarshaler = (*myUUID)(nil)
)

func (u myUUID) MarshalBSONValue() (bsontype.Type, []byte, error) {
    return bson.TypeBinary, bsoncore.AppendBinary(nil, bson.TypeBinaryUUID, []byte(u.UUID[:])), nil
}

func (u *myUUID) UnmarshalBSONValue(typ bsontype.Type, value []byte) error {
    if typ != bson.TypeBinary {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal %v into a Binary", typ)
    }
    subtype, bin, rem, ok := bsoncore.ReadBinary(value)
    if subtype != bson.TypeBinaryUUID {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal binary subtype %v into a UUID", subtype)
    }
    if len(rem) > 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("value has extra data: %v", rem)
    }
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("value does not have enough bytes")
    }
    *u = myUUID{UUID: uuid.UUID(bin)}
    return nil
}

type Person struct {
    Name string `bson:"name"`
    Sign myUUID `bson:"sign"`
}

func main() {
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(context.Background())

    db := client.Database("mydatabase")
    collection := db.Collection("people")

    signUUID := myUUID{UUID: uuid.New()}

    person := Person{
        Name: "John",
        Sign: signUUID,
    }

    if _, err = collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), person); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var p Person

    if err := collection.FindOne(context.Background(),
        bson.M{"sign": signUUID},
    ).Decode(&p); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%+v\n", p)
}
```